# angularjs upload and iterate over json file records

Tags: angularjs, json, file-upload

I have functionality, where i have a upload box, where i will browse my json file and will upload and submit it, when i submit it my controller will be called to handle it, where i need to iterate the uploaded json file line by line and as key value pair. for this tried using `angular.forEach(data)` as given below, but it does not working. what would be the possible way we can do this. rather than using $http can we do it with factory?

```
{
"outer" 
[
"A" : "aaaa",
"B" : "bbbb"
],
"C" : "c"
"D" : "d"
},

{
"C" : "c"
"D" : "d"
"E"  : "e"
}
```

### What i tried:

```
mapApp.factory('formDataObject',function($resource){
    return $resource("",{},{
                upload: {
                            method: 'POST',
                            transformResponse: function(data){
                                     var fd = new FormData();
                                     angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) 
                                  {
                                     fd.append(key, value);
                                     return fd;
                                 });
                            }
                }
}
)});
```

### Adding sample example:

in this below example, i could see the file content uploaded, here what i want to do is, i want to iterate each rows dynamically.

http://jsfiddle.net/6aG4x/1242/

Comment: define "not working". What debugging have you done? What goes wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I derived my answer. Find the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aG4x/1245/) for working piece of code.

### Code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

myapp.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.showContent = function($fileContent){
        $scope.content = $fileContent;
        $scope.aa = JSON.parse($scope.content);
        alert('length->' + $scope.aa.length +'--->'+angular.toJson($scope.aa));
        //alert($scope.content.value.data); // not working
        angular.forEach($scope.aa, function (key, value) {
        //  alert('key->'+key+'ZValue->'+value); // disaply each letter
        });
    };
  });

myapp.directive('onReadFile', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            var fn = $parse(attrs.onReadFile);

            element.on('change', function(onChangeEvent) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(onLoadEvent) {
                    scope.$apply(function() {
                        fn(scope, {$fileContent:onLoadEvent.target.result});
                    });
                };

                reader.readAsText((onChangeEvent.srcElement || onChangeEvent.target).files[0]);
            });
        }
    };
});
```